# PreDestroy in Spring version 2.6.4 not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Any problem with spring version 2.6.4, @PreDestroy not working.

@PostConstruct is working, but @PreDestroy does not work.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;


@Slf4j
@Component
public class RestartApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    public void ala() {
        log.info("Running PostConstruct...");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void restartApp() {
        log.info("Running PreDestroy...");
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you close the context?

Comment: @MichałKrzywański, I just test by clicking stop on IDE.

Comment: Which probably forcefully terminates the JVM, preventing any clean-up to be performed at all. What happens if you run it command line and use Ctrl+C to terminate the process?

Comment: @RobSpoor, it's working if run by command line

Comment: So your IDE indeed does not gracefully shut down your application.